How to import json files in node v22
i was configuring a rollup.config.mjs file and
this is how i used to import json files
import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };
as far i have tested it works in node 20 without any errors but a warning of
(node:34471) ExperimentalWarning: Importing JSON modules is an experimental feature and might change at any time
but in node v22 it is not working
right now i am using node 20 for rollup thanks to nvm(node version manager).
i am expecting to know if there is way to import .json files in node v22
thank you for your time.

try -> with: { type: 'json' },`  assert has been dropped, more info -> https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/51622

yup with keyword worked and i could rollup event without @rollup/plugin-json thanks alot

As mentionned in @keith comment, you should do this since node22:
import packageJson from "./package.json" with { type: "json" };

or for dynamic import:
const { default } = await import('./file.json', {with: {type: 'json' }});

